# Howto limit size of SVN repository for each user

Tags: svn, ubuntu-14.04

I already read from:

- Quotas
- Pre-Commits

Where do I define the repository size limits for
a) Quotas and
b) Pre-Commits?

Could you give an example script?

I found a pre-commit example script on limiting the size for a repository at [LINK](http://www.thedumbterminal.co.uk/posts/2006/09/how_to_limit_the_size_of_a_subversion_repository.html).
But where do I put this script called 'max-repo-size.py'?

```
#!/bin/bash
#commit hook to limit the size of a repos
REPOS=\"$1\"
TXN=\"$2\"

#max size for repos
QUOTA=\"100\"

MEGS=`du -sm $REPOS | sed -r \"s/^([0-9\\.]+).+/\\1/\"`

if [ \"$MEGS\" -gt \"$QUOTA\" ]; then
    #send error message to stderr
    echo \"Repository is over ${QUOTA}M in size\" 1>&2
    exit 1;
fi
exit 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your [link](http://www.thedumbterminal.co.uk/posts/2006/09/how_to_limit_the_size_of_a_subversion_repository.html) already contains the folder where your script should be placed:

```
If our repository was located here:
/var/lib/svn/repos

Then we need to create a pre-commit hook file here:
/var/lib/svn/repos/hooks/pre-commit
```

Rename your script to `pre-commit`, put it in `hooks` folder, and that is all. The code you provided looks like UNIX shell, not python, therefore there is no need to add any extension to script file.

Comment: Yes, but it does not work for me. I need this script as python script. How does this script would look like in this case? Really rename file to pre-commit or rename it to pre-commit.py?